# Generated ASPX Page has 4 Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I used Visual Studio 2010 yesterday to create a new .aspx form using the **Installed Templates** and selecting **Web Form using Master Page**.

Now, as you can see in the screen capture below, I have 4 errors on the page associated with the page directive that VS created.

Yesterday, I marked this up to Windows or Visual Studio needing to be restarted, but I kept working.

I shut the PC off when I went home, and everything loaded up fresh this morning, yet low and behold the error is still there.

Here is that first line with the page directive:

```
<%@ Page Title="Lawson MPRO AFE Detail" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/app.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AFE-details.aspx.cs" Inherits="spiderCS.pts.AFE_details" %>
```

Here are the errors (in case you can't read the screen capture):

- **Invalid expression term ')'**
- **; expected**
- **) expected**
- **Invalid expression term '>'**

### Does anyone know why I am seeing these errors or how to clear them up?

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Could you please post the whole code of this page?

Comment: just type it again and delete the original

Comment: I've seen that one before and I think it was a missing reference that caused the problem. Something went wrong when I created the project and one of the needed files didn't make it...

Comment: Could the hyphen `-` in the `AFE-details.aspx` page name be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Amit Joki's advice, I deleted the whole page and recreated it.

The problem returned.

However, Visual Studio 2010 will compile, debug and run the website still **if** I close the text so that the HTML in that file is not displayed.

Apparently, it is not a true bug in my code, but some kind of bug in the VS IDE.